# Self assigned IP address 169.254... on Panasonic TV

Tags: ip

I have a Netgear router using DHCP, Windows 7 Laptop, Panasonic WiFi tv and iphone 3 on my home network. If I power up all items everything works fine. If power down the Laptop the tv stops working on the network and returns the 169.254... IP address. If I reboot the router the tv returns a good IP and works fine. Is this normal?

I've tried a static IP address for the tv inside and outside the DHCP range and the tv always works on the internet but the iPhone app to control the tv does not and I can't ping the tv when using a static IP.

I would like to avoid rebooting the router when I switch the laptop off. Is this possible or is this the way things work?

Comment: is your laptop connected to the router by wifi or by ethernet cable?

Comment: In your system settings for you TV, what IP does it say is the default gateway? That IP address should match the router and no other device.

Answer (score -1):

Try reserving the IP Addresses to the MAC Addresses that is connecting. This way everytime the device connects it will have the same IP and any new device will get  an unassigned IP Address. What model is your router?.

Comment: The router is a Netgear DG834Gv5. I'm not very experienced at networking, how do I do this?

Comment: I have tried reserving IP to MAC addresses for the laptop, laptop and TV and then laptop,TV and iPhone with the same outcome - when I power down the Laptop the TV can't get the IP from the router so it sets 169,254... its self. At this point the iPhone works fine on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like either your ISP is handing out public IPs to your devices (which is unnecessary - and you are probably paying extra for this) or your ISP has some sort of configuration on the router to only allow up to X devices.

My advice is always take the router the ISP gives you and put it in the trash. Go out and buy a Linksys (or other router) that is compatible with DD-WRT.

Or if your ISP insists on requiring that router - you can just plug a router into that router and that should solve IP issues.

Edit:
Why was this downvoted? I have multiple IPs from my ISP and the only way to reallocate them is to power cycle the modem. And if you plug in another device it gets a local 169 address.

Comment: 1. Everything is WiFi

Comment: I believe the IP for the TV is self assigned by the tv because it can't get an ip from the router.